# layout doesn't render well in different browsers

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser, positioning

I am making a layout for a website. It's still in development anyway it is displayed good enough on Google Chrome and Opera but not on Firefox and Internet Explorer. In Chrome it looks okay but maybe the positioning isn't done correctly anyway. Can you help me to fix it?

**HTML body**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="top-header">
<div id="logo1">
scritta
<img src="CS-G-100.png" class="logo" />
</div>
<nav id="top-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pulsante2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pulsante3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pulsante4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pulsante5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="kenburns" class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="1">
</div>
</header>
<section id="main-section">
<aside id="left">
</aside>
<article id="main-content">
</article>
<aside id="right">
</aside>
<footer id="the-footer">
<div id="center-footer">
Centro fisioterapico San Giusto Via Romana Est 78/2 Porcari p. iva : 01532540463
</div>
</footer>
</section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {

width:100%;
margin:18px 20px 20px 20px;
display: box;                     /* As specified */
display: -moz-box;                /* Mozilla */
display: -webkit-box;             /* WebKit */
box-pack: center;                  /* As specified */
-moz-box-pack: center;             /* Mozilla */
-webkit-box-pack: center;          /* WebKit */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(sfondo-6.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}

#wrapper {
border: 1px solid black;
width:1024px;
height:768px;
padding: 20px;
background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1)  100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color- stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(238,238,238,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* W3C */

}
#top-header {
position:absolute;
width:1022px;
height:234px;
display:block;
border:1px solid black; 
z-index:1;
background-color:#d2e5e3;
}

#top-nav {
position:relative;
width:700px;
display:block;
border:1px solid black;
top:-119px;
right:-321px;
z-index:2;
background-color:#d2e4e8;
}

#top-nav li {
display: inline;
/* Align children to the horizontal center of this box */
box-align: center;              /* As specified */
-moz-box-align: center;         /* Mozilla */
-webkit-box-align: center;      /* WebKit */
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
width:120px;
height:25px;
background:#5DBCD2;
opacity:0.7;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
transition:transform 2s, opacity 2s, background 2s;
-webkit-transition::transform 2s, opacity 2s, background 2s;
-moz-transition:transform 2s, opacity 2s, background 2s;
-o--transform 2s, opacity 2s, background 2s;
}

#top-nav-li:hover {
transform-rotate:(360deg);
-webkit-transform:(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
opacity:1px;
background:#0F3;
}

#top-nav li {
display:inline-block;   
}

#left-nav {
position:absolute;
border:1px solid black;
padding:0px;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:2;
text-decoration:none;


}

#left-nav ul {
position:relative;
left:0px;
display:block;  
}

#left-nav li {
margin:0px opx 10px 0px;
display:block;
position:relative;
border-radius:0px 10px 0px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius:0px 10px 0px 10px;
-o-border-radius:0px 10px 0px 10px;
-moz-border-radius:0px 10px 0px 10px;
-ms-border-radius:0px 10px 0px 10px;
background-color:#9ED09D;
transition:opacity 2s;
-moz-transition:opacity 2s;
-o-transition:opacity 2s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 2s;
}

#left-nav li:hover {
opacity:1;  
}


#left {
position:relative;
float:left;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 20px;
width:256px;
height:620px;

}

#right {
float:left;
border: 1px solid black;
padding:20px;
width:256px;
height:620px;
}


#main-content {
float:left;
border: 1px solid black;
padding:20px;
width:386px;
height:620px;
}

#the-footer {
display:table;
clear:both;
width:100%;
height:50px;
border:1px solid black;
}

#rollover {
position:relative;
top:-112px;
left:490px;
border:1px solid black;
width:500px;
height:200px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;

}

#logo1{
position:relative;
top:47px;
left:20px;
}

.logo {

}

.center-text {
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;  
}

#center-footer {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how it is displayed on Google Chrome: (the best rendering of the 3)
[image: Google Chrome]

Here is a screenshot of how it is displayed on Firefox:
[image]
[image]

Here is a screenshot of how it is displayed on Internet Explorer: (better than firefox but not centered like in Google Chrome)

[image]

I give you the jfiddle:

Here it is with the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gwpbk/

And here the full screen view:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gwpbk/embedded/result/

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few tweaks you need to implement on your CSS. But I don't think it is a good idea to give you just a solution for this exact problem because you are you to face similar problems once and again. Probably sooner than you expect.

CSS is a complex subject. While you try to learn it, I suggest you use a CSS Reset.

All browsers have default CSS styles for rendering the different html elements and those rules are usually different between different browsers.

A CSS Reset is set of CSS rules that try to minimize the differences between browsers, thus bringing a more similar experienced when you add your own CSS. I suggest you check [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). Having a look at [Html5Boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/) want do any harm either.

Comment: I didn't mention it sorry, but i already use also normalize.css as an additional css to my css file in the web page. About Html5Boilerplate i know it and i will try to use it in the future, anyway if possible i would like if someone could help me to fix this page only for now, because i need it working asap. @CarlesAndres